# What's the difference between a stackpanel with datatemplates or a listview with listitems

Tags: c#, wpf, rest, xaml, lazy-loading

I'm creating a WPF program that consumes rest api data.  I want to implement lazyloading and infinite scroll on the data and programmatically create and add either custom data templates or listitems very similar to this design [image]

I'm just confused as to which approach to take and what benefits/costs each provides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy choices:

Everyone uses MVVM so use MVVM.

Data Templating is a fundamental of wpf and building UI in code is not recommended - so use data templating.

You can dynamically add templates to resources by building xaml as strings. This is the MS recommended way to build any dynamic UI.  Those strings can come from flat files, a database directly or a web service and you can build them by manipulating txt files or serialising controls.

A huge plus of this is you have the markup "right there". So when things go pear shaped you can paste into an experimental solution and see the errors light up in the xaml or see what the user is seeing.

If datatype associated templating doesn't suit for some reason then you could write a datatemplateselector and put your logic in there.

I'm not sure how you expect that to scroll exactly but I'd go with a listbox, some datatemplates associated with a type per view. Assuming the items can have different views - you just seem to have that "gilded" button or tag as an option.

Load your data into viewmodels with one per row.

.Add to an Observablecollection which is a public property in a viewmodel.

Bind that to the itemssource of a listbox.

They are then templated into UI.

A listbox has a scroller built in but you could re-template if you wanted to scroll using some other approach.

Answer (score 2):

A `StackPanel` is a `Panel` that arranges child elements into a single line that can be oriented either horizontally or vertically.

A `ListView` is an `ItemsControl` that you can bind to an `IEnumerable` of objects and is used to present a collection of items.

What you should do is to create an `ItemsControl` with an `ItemTemplate` that corresponds to a scrollable item in the list. There is a basic example available [here](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) and you will find a lot more examples online.

Comment: Your descriptions of both controls are, in fact, the same: both controls can present a number of child elements. What is the fundamental difference? For me, that question is relevant, as I noticed that the asterisk for a column width works in a StackPanel but not in a DataGrid, and the Expander control works better in a DataGrid than in a StackPanel